# get Published assets url from out side the extension yii1

Tags: yii, yii1.x, yii-booster

I am making a plugin [File Manager](http://plugins.idowstech.com) for `redactorJs` to be used in `Yii1 Framework` and i have some custom view files and a controller that are used inside the plugin, inside those view files i have to reference some `js` and `css` files from that plugin directory.

For RedActor i am using YiiBooster extension. I have placed my plugin inside the **`extensions/booster/assets/redator/plugins/my_plugin`**, now when yii initializes `booster` it publishes all assets to the web assets directory means to the `assets` folder inside my project root, i need to get that path that it creates with the random directory name, can any one guide me how can i 
get that. i tried using

```
Yii:import('application.extensions.booster.components.Booster');
```

and then trying to access `Booster::_assetsUrl` but it says

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant '_assetsUrl'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use the

```
Yii::app()->booster->getAssetsUrl()
```

to get the published assets path for the YiiBooster Extension.